# Browsers suddently report touch support on a non touch screen system

Tags: windows-10, browser, touchscreen

I am puzzled: a windows 10 system suddently reports that it supports touch, even though it acutally doesn't. There is a 2nd monitor connected - but non touch. At first I thought it was the latest browser update but all Browsers I tried (Chrome, Firefox, Edge, IE) report the same result (all green):

https://patrickhlauke.github.io/touch/tests/pointer-multitouch-detect.html

```
navigator.maxTouchPoints    256
navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0    true
navigator.maxTouchPoints > 1    true
```

I did not install any software nor was there a major windows update recently. In the device manager (Human Interface Devices section) there is no touchscreen listed. What else can it be?

Using Windows 10.0.18362 Build 18362.
Disabling touch in all 4 Browsers is not an option - I want to fix the underlying problem...